# Difference between a single (OPTIONAL) MATCH clause and multiple

Tags: neo4j

What is the difference between

```
OPTIONAL MATCH clauseA, clauseB
```

and

```
OPTIONAL MATCH clauseA
OPTIONAL MATCH clauseB
```

I get different behavior depending on which form I use.

For example:

```
START n=node(111)
OPTIONAL MATCH n<-[links_n_in]-(n_from),n-[links_n_out]->(n_to)
RETURN n,COLLECT(n_from) AS n_from,COLLECT(links_n_in) AS links_n_in,COLLECT(n_to) AS n_to,COLLECT(links_n_out) AS links_n_out
```

which is designed to return a node; it's incoming relationships and from nodes; it's outgoing relationship and to nodes.

I have a test graph consisting of Node 111 which has 4 outgoing relationships each of which points to the same Node (I have other test cases in which 111 points to different Nodes). Executing the query as above returns only Node 111 in column 'n'. The columns for 'n_from', 'links_n_in', 'n_to', 'links_n_out' are empty.

If I modify the query to:

```
START n=node(111)
OPTIONAL MATCH n<-[links_n_in]-(n_from)
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[links_n_out]->(n_to)
RETURN n,COLLECT(n_from) AS n_from,COLLECT(links_n_in) AS links_n_in,COLLECT(n_to) AS n_to,COLLECT(links_n_out) AS links_n_out
```

then the n_to and link_n_out columns are populated as expected.

Comment: Can you give a more full example query? Depending on the parts of the patterns matched before these may act differently. Are patternA and patternB connected to eachother?

Comment: Updated with sample queries and explanation. So is it the case that a single OPTIONAL MATCH with multiple clauses tries to match a single subgraph, as opposed to multiple OPTIONAL MATCH statements which try to match multiple distinct subgraphs?

Comment: Can you share your sample graph on console.neo4j.org? That would be awesoem.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/n8pgxoc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first form treats it as a single extended pattern that must match entirely.

The second form treats them as distinct optional patterns, and can match the two separately.

So your results make sense, when you think about what it's doing--if the whole OPTIONAL MATCH pattern isn't found, it doesn't match any of the OPTIONAL MATCH pattern.

Comment: Hmmm.  This isn't very intuitive.  I thought the point of the OPTIONAL keyword was that the match was optional. Prior to 2.0, I achieved what I wanted by appending a question mark to 'links_n_in' and 'links_n_out' in the multi-clause form. so I guess the two question marks translate into two OPTIONAL MATCH clauses in 2.0?

Comment: Yeah, two question marks = two optional match clauses.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a case where you have disconnected patterns each with a question mark that might work without splitting it up, but it doesn't--you'll always need to split them up if you want to get optional results from one part of the pattern--because they'll never match the whole pattern if one part is missing. For example: http://console.neo4j.org/r/ivs84r

Comment: OPTIONAL MATCH says: "can I find a set of nodes that match this pattern, given the nodes passed in?" if not, it returns null for the new identifiers.